# How to Control Thorlab Laser Diode Driver (KLD101) with Python

Tags: python

Can I control the driver with python?

I saw that the driver runs with software Kinesis and the dll files under the software uses C#,  Labview or other .Net languages.

Is there any way to control it with python?

Also I want to know what IronPython do. Is it only used to embed python codes to C#?

Answer (score 0):

Thorlabs provides an ActiveX control that you can use to control your instrument on Windows. On Python, the easiest way may be to use Qt, which provides support for ActiveX and COM:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/activeqt-container.html

You can use it with either PyQt (licensed under GPL) or PySide (licensed under LGPL), depending on which software license is right for your application case. Here is an example to get you inspired:

https://gist.github.com/sunjerry019/e51504317f523c21ef12da5155c1354f

Other GUI tools like wxPython also provide support for ActiveX controls.